# ESLint conflicts with eslint-plugin-import and typescript-eslint

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I want to include the rule [no-unpublished-import](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unpublished-import.md) from [eslint-plugin-node](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node), however, it is conflicting with my current `.eslintrc` because I am using [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) and [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript).

It is my current configuration:

```
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", // Specifies the ESLint parser
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
        "prettier", // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and displays prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint" // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.json",
        "ecmaVersion": 6, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
        "sourceType": "module" // Allows for the use of imports
    },
    "rules": {
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [".js", ".ts"]
            },
            // use <root>/tsconfig.json
            "typescript": {
                "alwaysTryTypes": true // always try to resolve types under `<root>@types` directory even it doesn't contain any source code, like `@types/unist`
            }
        }
    },
    "root": true
}
```

The code compiles correctly, however, if I add to the extends option the `plugin:node/recommended` the compilation process will fail:

```
  1:1   error  Import and export declarations are not supported yet  node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  1:43  error  "express" is not found                                node/no-missing-import
  2:1   error  Import and export declarations are not supported yet  node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
```

My `package.json` includes the `node": ">=12.0.0`. Also, this rule should be ignored because I am using typescript. On the other hand, I am just exporting types from `express` because the module don't use it.

According to this [issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1027) the conflict should be resolved by `eslint-plugin-node`.

How can I accomplish the merge of both plugins? Do I have to go disabling rules one by one?

**UPDATED:**
It seems it was asked in this [issue](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/issues/205#issuecomment-590753223) on the `eslint-plugin-node` repository. It works for `no-unsupported-features` and `no-missing-import`, however, it is still failing with the import definition of `express` with `no-extraneous-import`.

**UPDATED 2:**
It seems `eslint-plugin-node` is working on a enhancement to accomplish it. [Issue here](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/issues/186)

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, you have to add the option `tryExtension` to include TS files:

```
"settings": {
    "node": {
        "tryExtensions": [".js", ".json", ".node", ".ts", ".d.ts"]
    },
```

To solve the `no-unsupported-features/es-syntax`, according to this [issue](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/issues/205) about adding information to works with TypeScript, if you work with transpilers you will have to ignore it under `rules`:

```
"node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax": ["error", { "ignores": ["modules"] }],
```

On the other hand, use just types and not the code is not supported yet by the `eslint-plugin-node`. They are working on a [enhancement](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/issues/186) to solve it. However, to solve the `no-missing-import`, you have to add to the `resolvePath` the `node_modules/@types`:

```
"node": {
    "resolvePaths": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "tryExtensions": [".js", ".json", ".node", ".ts", ".d.ts"]
},
```

Even so, it will generate a `no-extraneous-import` because it doesn't detect the module, because it is just a type. Meanwhile they are working on this enhancement, you can use `allowModules` under that rule for workaround:

```
"node/no-extraneous-import": ["error", {
    "allowModules": ["express"]
}]
```

Comment: For some reason it shows I downvoted this answer, but I've never seen it before. 

I can't remove my downvote unless you edit the answer.  You have a double comma in "However,, to solve..." Remove that and I can fix this.